# New to Django. Can the admin panel be used as the primary app?

Tags: django-admin

All, 
I've searched the forum but I'm sure I'm not searching the right terms.
Apologizes in advance for what I'm sure is a redundant question.

I have a VERY simple single table database that was managed by a foxpro app for a long time.  I'm trying to move it to a web based app.

It seems like with a little customization using django-suit, the admin panel for the database really provides everything I would need.

Looking for PROS/CONS if this is appropriate.
Is this a common approach for super simple DB apps?

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Django so I cannot advise you on that.

> I have a VERY simple single table database that was managed by a
>   foxpro app for a long time. I'm trying to move it to a web based app.

The assumption here is that the data table itself is a Foxpro 'native' data table (a DBF file with perhaps one or more Index files - IDX or CDX and maybe a Memo file - FPT).

However we have created Web based apps which still utilize the Old Foxpro data tables.
We created VB.Net apps which use Foxpro ODBC Connections to/from the old Foxpro data tables from our old legacy system and it works just fine.

Otherwise you will have to re-create your Foxpro data table from scratch into another database of your choice M$ SQL Server, MySQL, Django or whatever and then build your web-centric app around it.

Good Luck